# Conditionally replace values with NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

I'm trying to conditionally replace values with NA in R.

Here's what I've tried so far using `dplyr` package.

**Data**

```r
have <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                   gender = c("Female", "I Do Not Wish to Disclose", "Male"))
```

**First try**

```r
want = as.data.frame(have %>% 
        mutate(gender = replace(gender, gender == "I Do Not Wish to Disclose", NA))
    )
```

This gives me an error.

**Second try**

```r
want = as.data.frame(have %>% 
        mutate(gender = ifelse(gender == "I Do Not Wish to Disclose", NA, gender))
    )
```

This runs without an error but turns `Female` into `1`, `Male` into `3` and `I Do Not Wish to Disclose` into `2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is case where the column is `factor`.  Convert to `character` and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
have %>% 
    mutate(gender = as.character(gender), 
    gender = replace(gender, gender == "I Do Not Wish to Disclose", NA))
```

---

The change in values in `gender` is when it gets coerced to its integer storage values

```
as.integer(factor(c("Male", "Female", "Male")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the very neat function `na_if()` from `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)

have <- data.frame(gender = c("F", "M", "NB", "I Do Not Wish to Disclose"))

have |> mutate(gender2 = na_if(gender, "I Do Not Wish to Disclose"))
```

Output:

```
#>                      gender gender2
#> 1                         F       F
#> 2                         M       M
#> 3                        NB      NB
#> 4 I Do Not Wish to Disclose    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>